# Javascript compilation interpretation and page rendering

Tags: javascript

As soon you open browser tab window object is ready then when we input url and hit enter it will hit the destination and gets the response ,once the response comes as string then browser interprets this and created nodes for each tag and constructs a dom tree(object graph).And document property of window object will be assigned this dom tree .

```
document={...
....
function getelementbyid(...){
.....
}
}
```

My questions are,

- will node created for script tag also
- Will javascript compilation(scope chain construction) happens before constructing dom tree or after or during construction or during page rendering.

Comment: The content of `<script>` tags is evaluated as soon as the `</script>` tag is seen unless the tag has the "async" or "deferred" attributes. So it's done *while* the DOM is being constructed.

Comment: The Javascript has can access anything in the DOM tree that was created before the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I have one doubt regarding functions in javascript.Everywhere i read about functions it is said "functions are objects" . During compilation time scopr chain will be created .when objects are created .(in java when we say new on class name object will be created) but here in javascript  when object will be created (since its a scripting language instructions are directly executed by rumtime envt.) ,when object will be created,Please clarify